# Kotlin + Rx: required Consumer, found KFunction

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, rx-android

I am using Kotlin + Retrofit + Rx. I want to extract one of requests into function:

```
fun getDataAsync(onSuccess: Consumer<Data>, onError: Consumer<in Throwable>) {
    ApiManager.instance.api
            .getData("some", "parameters", "here")
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(Consumer {
                time = System.currentTimeMillis()
                onSuccess.accept(it)
            }, onError)
}


fun onButtonClick() {
    getDataAsync(this::onSuccess, this::onError)
}

private fun onSuccess(data: Data) {}

private fun onError(throwable: Throwable) {}
```

I get an errors in line `getDataAsync(this::onSuccess, this::onError)`:

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is KFunction1<@ParameterName Data, Unit> but Consumer<Data> was expected

Type mismatch: inferred type is KFunction1<@ParameterName Throwable, Unit> but Consumer<in Throwable> was expected
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of passing a Consumer as a parameter you could just pass a function

```
fun getDataAsync(onSuccess: (Data) -> Unit, onError: (Throwable) -> Unit) {
     ApiManager.instance.api
        .getData("some", "parameters", "here")
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe({
            time = System.currentTimeMillis()
            onSuccess(it)
        }, onError)
}


fun onButtonClick() {
   getDataAsync(this::onSuccess, this::onError)
}

private fun onSuccess(data: Data) {}

private fun onError(throwable: Throwable) {}
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that your method `getDataAsync` requires an object of type `Consumer` for both arguments, while you are providing a method reference. Please note that the same error happens in Java.

In order to solve it you can either declare both arguments of `getDataAsync` as function reference, or create an implementation of `Consumer`.

#### First solution

```
fun getDataAsync(onSuccess: (Data) -> Unit, onError: (Throwable) -> Unit) {

}

fun onButtonClick() {
    getDataAsync(::onSuccess, ::onError)
}


private fun onSuccess(data: Data) {

}

private fun onError(throwable: Throwable) {}
```

#### Second solution

```
fun getDataAsync(onSuccess: Consumer<Data>, onError: Consumer<in Throwable>) {

}

fun onButtonClick() {
    getDataAsync(Consumer { data ->
        // do something
    }, Consumer { throwable ->
        // do something
    })
}
```

Comment: In Java method reference can be passed as a Consumer. And any other single-method interface